# Unity3D is crashing when hitting play – and when Oculus is on

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I am using Unity 5.2.2f1 with the Oculus Rift and Windows 7. Everything was working well till... one hour ago. I first ran a build that played smoothly. I then moved away from my computer; when I came back, it was shutting down. Upon turning the computer back on, Unity started to crash anytime I hit play and the Oculus is on. If the Oculus is turned off before I start Unity, everything works perfectly. This is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwNJG1IngzyGRW05X2Q4Y2w2VVE/view?usp=sharing) to the Unity Editor log.

This is part of the log, where the crash happens:

*Completed reload, in  0.636 seconds
Initializing Unity.PackageManager (PackageManager) v5.2.2 for Unity v5.2.2f1*

(...)

*Native extension for OSXStandalone target not found
Native extension for WindowsStandalone target not found
Native extension for LinuxStandalone target not found
Native extension for WebGL target not found
Native extension for SamsungTV target not found
Native extension for Tizen target not found
Native extension for Android target not found*

*04/22/16 19:07:47: [CAPI] LibOVR module is located at C:\Windows\system32\LibOVRRT64_0_7.dll*

*(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/VR/Oculus/VRDeviceOculus.cpp Line: 46)*

***Crash!!!***

*SymInit: Symbol-SearchPath: 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/MonoEmbedRuntime;.;C:\Users\vcladmin\Documents\maze;C:\Program*

(...)

Comment: I see I am getting downvoted. If this is the wrong way to ask a question, please help me to improve it.

Comment: The question is a bit broad, and doesn't really provide any hints as to what could be causing the problem.  Have you tried running an example or very simple project under the same conditions?  If you can get that working the problem is likely in your code (in which case you should post that).  If nothing seems to work, this is probably a better question for tech support.

Comment: Thanks, I hoped someone could look at the log. I will ask in the Unity forum.

Comment: No worries.  That log does look like more of something to pass by the Unity people.  Good luck, and if you do have code issues bring'm on back!

Comment: hi @Nottolina  you should go ahead and put the log (or at least some sections of it) right in your question. click "Edit".  nobody's going to bother clicking through to read a log, you know?

Comment: @JoeBlow I did it, thanks.

Comment: what Android version is the oculus running?

Comment: @Programmer, please do you know where I can find that information?

Comment: Never mind. I mistook oculus for something else. When you cameback and your computer was re-starting....was that a re-start after win7 update? Can you create a new simple scene and see if that crashes too. I want to rule out project corruption.

Comment: I have tried a new simple scene but it's not running either.

Comment: What do you mean that it is not running? Is it crashing like the old scene? Also the re-start you mentioned about, did the re-start happen after update and was unity open when the computer re-started. Please try to answer these questions.It would be good to use @ to reply to me so that I will be notified each time.

Comment: @Programmer, thank you for your help. I don't think that

Comment: @Programmer, thank you for your help. The new scene is not crashing, but once I hit "play" the scene does not "animate" (I can't move into the 3D scene).  I don't think that the re-start happened after an update; I was away from my computer for 5 minutes, and when I came back, windows was shutting down. After I turned the computer on again, it was behaving weirdly. For example, I created a new folder in windows' directory, and then I tried to rename it, but the computer told me that folder did not exist. After restarting the computer again, the folder was there, already with the new name.

Comment: The chances that you got virus is high. Did you enable System Restore? If so, can you try System Restore to restore your computer to where it was two days ago. You wont lose your personal/project files but you may loose Software installed within those time.

Comment: Are you using a consumer Oculus Rift with the latest Oculus Home installed? If so you're using the wrong version of Unity - you need to be using 5.3.4p1 or the latest 5.4 beta. If you're using a DK2 with the 0.8 SDK then I think the version of Unity you're using should work.

Comment: @Programmer and mattnewport, thank you both for your help. I will be back working on this on Sunday and i will let you know how it goes.

Comment: has anyone else had access to your PC in that "5 minutes", if it's not a human causing something dumb to happen then the chances are pretty high it's some sort of virus, but again, who downloads it, if you where not there?

Comment: @Martin, see my answer below. It was "Dell updates" that updated the drivers and for some reason changed the NVIDIA driver back to an old version that does not support Oculus.

Comment: @Programmer, I found that the problem was with the NVIDIA driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Programmer, I have used System Restore as you suggested.
The suggested restore point was at an install of "Dell update", right at the time of the crash. Proceeding with the restore, I realized that the NVIDIA driver was being restored *from an old version (266), to the newer version (358)* (that's the version I need to make the Oculus work). After the restore everything went back to normal. Then I tried to install Dropbox. After the install, the computer turned off again and, like before, once restarting, the Oculus was not working anymore. I checked the Oculus setup and it said it needed a new  NVIDIA driver. So something is happening that makes the NVIDIA driver go from 358 to the old one. I don't understand why. What would you suggest?

A friend told me that probably the "Dell Command update" thinks that the new NVIDIA driver is the wrong one, so it restores it to the old one every time it updates. We have disabled automatic Dell Command updates.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah auto update is what's happening in the background. Good thing you figured it out. Remember System Restore next time somethings works today fails to work tomorrow.